# How can I install OpenCV 'samples' library and have it work on armhf?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, arm, beagleboneblack

I have a working OpenCV library on my armhf machine, BeagleBone AI.

All for the `samples` library, I can perform most of the functions in the /opencv/samples/python/ directory.

Is there a particular way to install the `samples` lib. on a armhf machine?

Also...

This is what I am describing:

```
def main():
    import sys
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = 'fruits.jpg'

    fn = cv.samples.findFile(fn)
    img = cv.imread(fn, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

On line seven, you can see `fn = cv.samples.findFile(fn)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian Bullseye solves the issue...

with Debian Bullseye, the install w/ cmake is easy and just like the recommended way of installation from their `OpenCV` site.